# Type Error: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am a beginner to openCV and am trying to analyse an existing code for a sudoku solver.  There is this section of code which throws an error.

```
samples = np.float32(np.loadtxt('feature_vector_pixels.data'))
responses = np.float32(np.loadtxt('samples_pixels.data'))

model = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
model.train(samples, responses)
```

The error is as follows `Type Error: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars`.

The complete traceback is as below:

```
C:\Study stuff\FinalProject>c:\Python27\python.exe Sudoku.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sudoku.py", line 15, in <module>
    model.train(samples, responses)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Any idea as to what the issue is?

Comment: Do you have the full traceback?

Comment: @memoselyk I added the full traceback

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message that you are getting:

```
TypeError: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars
```

literally means: you have provided an array of **more than one element** in a place where a **single value** or **an array of a single element** was expected.

So one of the arguments passed to call `model.train(samples, responses)` requires and scalar... but which?

A look at the latest documentation of [KNearest class](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html), allow us to see the signature of the [StatsModel.train method](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#af96a0e04f1677a835cc25263c7db3c0c&gsc.tab=0):

> virtual bool cv::ml::StatModel::train ( InputArray samples, int layout, InputArray responses )

Apparently, a new **`layout`** argument was added. But it's [meaning](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/ded/group__ml.html#ga9c57a2b823008dda53d2c7f7059a8710&gsc.tab=0) is a little obscure from the documentation.

Without knowledge of the contents of you file, I can't tell if you need to pass `ROW_SAMPLE` or `COL_SAMPLE`, but armed with that information, I could find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980675/knn-train-in-cv2-with-opencv-3-0), whose solution was to add `cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE` as second argument to the train method:

```
model.train(samples, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs due to a series of refactoring operations made in the latest versions.
[Error fix](https://github.com/rcrespocano/opencv-python/issues/4)