# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars OpenCV 3.1 Python

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I am trying to use SVM with OpenCV 3.1 and Python 3.5. I am planning to use this simple code example as a test case.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

samples = np.array(np.random.random((4,2)), dtype = np.float32)
y_train = np.array([1.,0.,0.,1.], dtype = np.float32)

clf = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
clf.train(samples, y_train)
y_val = clf.predict(samples)
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. This error is generated while training the classifier. Since OpenCV has moved from 2.4 to 3.1 there are certain api calls which are repackaged. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Same error in train: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975695/type-error-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars

Comment: It didn't solve the problem above, but it solved the original problem that I was solving. So thanks. Also, hi from Bellevue.

Comment: did you try this :clf.train(samples, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, y_train)